# Parameterized jUnit test without changing runner

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit-runner

Is there a clean way to run parameterized jUnit 4 tests without changing the runner, i.e. without using
`@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`?

I have unit tests which require a special runner already and I can't replace this one with `Parameterized`. Maybe there is some kind of "runner chaining" so I could both runners at the same time? (Just a wild guess...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.junit.runners.Parameterized` is created by `org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder` by reflect mechanism. Maybe you could extend `Parameterized` as your own Runner: @RunWith(**MyParameterized**.class).

Comment: Thanks, good idea! Well, the special runner I need is not written by me and I have to use it as is. But I can apply your solution the other way around: I'll extend the special runner such that it has the same functionality as Parameterized. Let's see if JUnit's license allows some copy and paste. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I have released a framework with a couple of runners that are able to enforce parameterization on the test-class while allowing you to chain an arbitrary 3rd-party runner for the actual test-execution.

The framework is CallbackParams - (http://callbackparams.org) - and these are the runners:

- CallbackParamsRunner
- BddRunner

By using the framework annotation ...

- @WrappedRunner

... you can specify an arbitrary 3rd-party runner in this manner:

```
@RunWith(CallbackParamsRunner.class) // or @RunWith(BddRunner.class)
@WrappedRunner(YourSpecialRunner.class)
public class YourTest {
...
```

Parameterized tests with CallbackParams differ considerably from the traditional approach to test-parameterization, however. The reasons are explained in this [tutorial article](http://callbackparams.org/part1-maintain.html) with BddRunner explained [near the end of the tutorial article](http://callbackparams.org/part1-maintain.html#bdd).

For your first CallbackParams test you would probably prefer BddRunner, since it requires less boiler-plate stuff, but when you start reusing parameter values between different test-classes you are probably better off with CallbackParamsRunner, which demands stronger type-checking.

Also - with BddRunner you must not have any @Test-methods. Instead you must use the framework annotations @Given, @When and @Then. That requirement sometimes clash with those of the third-party runner but it usually works out quite well.

Good Luck!